# Correr aplicacion React en HTTPS

Tags: reactjs

estoy escribiendo una aplicacion web con React. Sucede que quiero hacer que la misma funcione sobre el protocolo HTTPS. Utilice set `HTTPS=true` pero de igual forma la aplicacion sigue funcionando en HTTP.

Alguien conoce otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Pero te funciona tambien el HTTPS?

Comment: No, sigue corriendo en HTTP. Supongo que en producción debe ser mas fácil hacerlo a diferencia que en modo desarrollo.